# SF2.1 RC1 - No Metadata Classes to process

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have done a clean install of Symfony 2 with composer, and created a bundle via `app/console`. I also created a database and generated some entities via `app/console`.

So now i execute `app/console doctrine:schema:create` to create the database scheme. Unfortunately, i get the following error:

```
No Metadata Classes to process.
```

I double checked the namespaces and everything seems to be correct, especially because it is all generated code. I also checked that `/resources/config/doctrine/*bundlename*.orm.php` exists, and it does.

Do I have to re-configure Doctrine in some way? What am i missing here? I've deleted cache several times without any luck. I tried the custom mapping in `config.yml`, without any result.

Running Xampp 1.8.0, PHP 5.4.4, Apache 2.4.2, Windows 7, Symfony 2.1 RC1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you done configure your driver option for doctrine correctly or there is no entity in entity folders (or YAML / XML mappings)

or you forgot to add @entity above your entity class doc-blocks

for doctrine configuration information :
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html

Comment: The entity is defined in PHP with annotations. The @ORM\Entity() line is also defined. I'm able to create and drop a database, so the database connection should be fine. I've been using the following guide: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: if you are using linux make sure your entity folder chmod is correct

Answer (score 1):

On top of your entity you have to use Doctrine:

```php
namespace Osiris\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Blog
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog")
 */
class Blog {
   ...
}
```

Then run php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql